# How do I get the value from a data-selected input option?

Tags: javascript

How can I get the data-selected's value from this input? Let's also say I only want the "title" value from that?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 //console.log("prdcl ready");
 $("#digital_object_prdcls__0__prdcl_links__0__ref_").on('keyup change', prdcl_link);
 $("#digital_object_prdcls__0__volume_num_").on('keyup change', prdcl_link);
 $("#digital_object_prdcls__0__issue_num_").on('keyup change', prdcl_link);

    function prdcl_link(){
  //console.log("entered function");
  var valp = {};
  valp = $("#digital_object_prdcls__0__prdcl_links__0__ref_").data('data-selected');
  console.log(valp);
        var valv = $("#digital_object_prdcls__0__volume_num_").val();
  //console.log(valv);
        var vali = $("#digital_object_prdcls__0__issue_num_").val();
  //console.log(vali);

   };
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="linker initialised" id="digital_object_prdcls__0__prdcl_links__0__ref_" data-label="Publication" data-label_plural="Publications" data-name="ref" data-path="digital_object[prdcls][0][prdcl_links][0]" data-url="/search.json" data-browse-url="/search.js?" data-selected="{"lock_version":0,"publication":"1111","publisher":"1111","title":"1111 (1111)","created_by":"admin","last_modified_by":"admin","create_time":"2016-06-01T14:46:46Z","system_mtime":"2016-06-01T14:46:46Z","user_mtime":"2016-06-01T14:46:46Z","jsonmodel_type":"prdcl_title","uri":"/prdcl_titles/9"}" data-multiplicity="one" data-format_template="title" data-types="["prdcl_title"]" style="display: none;">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the first `data-` chunk of the attribute in your code:

```
valp = $("#digital_object_prdcls__0__prdcl_links__0__ref_").data('selected');
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5

Comment: Also I just noted you use `data-selected="{"lock_version":0,` etc. Be aware that the 2nd quote closes the attribute value. You should escape that or alternate with single quotes, like data-selected=`"{'lock_version':0, `

Comment: There's no escaping in HTML attributes. And single quotes won't work, because `.data()` expects it to be JSON, and JSON requires double quotes.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I need to do some reading ;) So the example html will not given any trouble? Can still use single quotes to mark the start and end of the attribute value, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. yuriy636 has it correct in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using double quotes to structure the object inside `data-selected` you get invalid markup: the `data-selected` becomes just "{".

Fix the markup (use single quotes for example):

```
data-selected='{"lock_version":0,"publication":"1111","publisher":"1111","title":"1111 (1111)","created_by":"admin","last_modified_by":"admin","create_time":"2016-06-01T14:46:46Z","system_mtime":"2016-06-01T14:46:46Z","user_mtime":"2016-06-01T14:46:46Z","jsonmodel_type":"prdcl_title","uri":"/prdcl_titles/9"}'
```

And retrieve `data-selected` using:

`$('#digital_object_prdcls__0__prdcl_links__0__ref_').data('selected')`

Comment: or, using pure js, `var dt=JSON.parse(document.getElementById('digital_object_prdcls__0__prdcl_links__0__ref_').getAttribute('data-selected')).title;` ... there is fiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/6yqpugch/